# Check status of user during (server) interaction in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, database-performance, authorize-attribute

I have somewhat of a thought problem, where I'm not sure if what I already built can be done a lot more efficiently, so that's why I'll share my 'problem' here. (to be clear, everything I have built works, I'm just looking to make it more efficient).

I have a webapp made with MVC & SQL which has a log-in system etc for users.
A user has a status, which is an enum, and can be active, blocked etc and is stored in the database (along with other user-data).

Within my webapp I have made a custom AuthorizeAttr. for authorizing users on every call made (applied as a global filter).

However, the 'normal' authentication is based on the cookie, which does not change when I would change the user-status in the database. For instance, users can de-activate another user in the same group (when being Admin). These database changes are not taking immediate effect since by default the authorization only verifies the cookie, and the cookie is based on the status when logging in.

To fix this issue, I added some additional logic to my authorizationAttr, which on every request calls the database for the current user status (the enum), and then simply does some checks whether the user is allowed to continue, or a redirect is required.

Calling the database on every request seems (even just for 1 enum) seems to be a bit taxing on the server/db especially when the webapp would grow in popularity (= lots of users).

One idea I thought of was to cache the enum in session cache but for short periods of time (like 60 seconds), this would save some database calls, but obviously the user can still use the webapp for max 60seconds after being de-activated.

I could be wrong in thinking that these database calls are actually that taxing of course.

Any ideas for improvement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how do you know that checking status per request is too expensive? did you measure performance cost of checking user status in the database? have you created your custom cache without actually measuring the cost of simple solution? do you use ORM like hibernate? they have 2nd level cache built in so often there will be no roundtrip to the database.

i think it's way better to stick to the KISS principle rather than creating custom solution for a [difficult problem](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html). even if your database will be the bottleneck then usually buying additional hardware once is cheaper than maintaining overcomplicated solution for years

if your application grow, first thing you throw away is relation database

Comment: I did not do any performance testing yet, I am using Nhibernate and am aware that their cache might also ease the pressure of the database. I guess as you suggest I will keep it simple for now and when I start noticing actual issues I will dig a bit deeper. As I said, there is no actual performance problem yet, it was more a question out of curiosity than necessity.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using ADO.NET DataSets for your requirement? If you don't have multiple front-ends you could possibly read the login statuses initially into the dataset. All read/write operations could be made to this and you could later save your changes to the actual database. In case you have multiple front-ends, would it be possible for you to restrict all read/write/modify operations of one group to a single front-end instance? Because I guess you could use the dataset approach in that case as well.

Comment: Besides that I'm using nhibernate at the moment, I think going your way would be a bit too much change at this point,but interesting idea :) thx